# SQL server date time format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have date in below format -
yyyymmddhhmmss
Eg. 20160203081617

and I want it in below format -
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

How do I get it?

Comment: `201602030816171` seems to have an extra digit at the end.  Typo?

Comment: Sorry..please ignore the last "1"

Comment: you could use `FORMAT(datetime, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss')`,.

Comment: What is the data type of the existing date -- a date/time or a string?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your current date/time format is a string.

You can use the `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` function to convert the string to a `DATETIME2(3)` data type. Then from there display it in the string date/time format you want in your query.

```sql
DECLARE     @OldDateTime    AS VARCHAR(15)
            , @NewDateTime  AS DATETIME2(0) ;

/* original date/time format */
SELECT      @OldDateTime    = '20160203081617' ;

/* new date/time data type */
SELECT      @NewDateTime    = DATETIMEFROMPARTS
            (
                SUBSTRING ( @OldDateTime, 1, 4 )
                , SUBSTRING ( @OldDateTime, 5, 2 )
                , SUBSTRING ( @OldDateTime, 7, 2 )
                , SUBSTRING ( @OldDateTime, 9, 2 )
                , SUBSTRING ( @OldDateTime, 11, 2 )
                , SUBSTRING ( @OldDateTime, 13, 2 )
                , 0
            ) ;

/* old, new, and formatted date/time displays */
SELECT      @OldDateTime AS [yyyymmddhhmmss]
            , @NewDateTime AS [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss]
            , CONVERT ( VARCHAR(10), @NewDateTime, 103 ) + ' '
                + CONVERT ( VARCHAR(8), @NewDateTime, 8 ) AS [dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss] ;
```

If your current date time is already in a table column, you can add a computed column to convert the existing data to the `DATETIME2(3)` data type. And again, from there, change it to the display you want in your `SELECT` statement.

```sql
/* create existing table for demo */
CREATE TABLE dbo.ExistingTable
(
    [id]                INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [old_date_time]   VARCHAR(15)
) ;

/* insert existing data */
INSERT
    INTO    dbo.ExistingTable ( [old_date_time] )
    VALUES  ( '20160203081617' ) ;
```

Now create a computed column to convert the existing data.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.ExistingTable
    ADD [new_date_time]
    AS DATETIMEFROMPARTS
    (
        SUBSTRING ( [old_date_time], 1, 4 )     /* year */
        , SUBSTRING ( [old_date_time], 5, 2 )   /* month */
        , SUBSTRING ( [old_date_time], 7, 2 )   /* day */
        , SUBSTRING ( [old_date_time], 9, 2 )   /* hour */
        , SUBSTRING ( [old_date_time], 11, 2 )  /* minute */
        , SUBSTRING ( [old_date_time], 13, 2 )  /* second */
        , 0                                     /* millisecond */
    ) ;
```

Then use some `CONVERT` functions and concatenate the results to get the display you want.

```sql
SELECT      [old_date_time]
            , [new_date_time]
            , CONVERT ( VARCHAR(10), [new_date_time], 103 ) + ' '
                + CONVERT ( VARCHAR(8), [new_date_time], 8 )
                AS [formatted_new_date_time]
FROM        dbo.ExistingTable ;
```

This query should give you the following results:

```
old_date_time  | new_date_time           | formatted_new_date_time
------------------------------------------------------------------
20160203081617 | 2016-02-03 08:16:17.000 | 03/02/2016 08:16:17
```

Just occurred to me that your existing date/time could be stored as a `BIGINT`. In which case, the same applies -- except you convert to a `VARCHAR` first.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.ExistingTable
    ADD [new_date_time]
    AS DATETIMEFROMPARTS
    (
        SUBSTRING ( CAST ( [old_date_time] AS VARCHAR(15) ), 1, 4 )
        , SUBSTRING ( CAST ( [old_date_time] AS VARCHAR(15) ), 5, 2 )
        , SUBSTRING ( CAST ( [old_date_time] AS VARCHAR(15) ), 7, 2 )
        , SUBSTRING ( CAST ( [old_date_time] AS VARCHAR(15) ), 9, 2 )
        , SUBSTRING ( CAST ( [old_date_time] AS VARCHAR(15) ), 11, 2 )
        , SUBSTRING ( CAST ( [old_date_time] AS VARCHAR(15) ), 13, 2 )
        , 0
    ) ;
```